# Unable to compile workspace for unsolved reference to serial::Serial::waitReadable

Tags: ros, serial, catkin, compilation, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi to all,

I'm kind of new to ROS and I'm having a problem while compiling the catkin workspace on my laptop. I'm using ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04, and I'm trying to compile the `irobotcreate2ros` package (https://github.com/MirkoFerrati/irobotcreate2ros).

It requires the packages `serial` and `joy` to be installed. The problem is that when I compile the workspace, I received the following error:

`CMakeFiles/basic_commands.dir/src/irobotcreate2/OpenInterface.cpp.o: In function irobot::OpenInterface::getSensorPackets(int):`

`OpenInterface.cpp:(.text+0xf3c): undefined reference to serial::Serial::waitReadable()`

`CMakeFiles/basic_commands.dir/src/irobotcreate2/OpenInterface.cpp.o: In function irobot::OpenInterface::streamSensorPackets():`

`OpenInterface.cpp:(.text+0x12a5): undefined reference to serial::Serial::waitReadable()`

`collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

`make[2]: [/home/myhome/Projects/ros/indigo/catkin_ws/devel/lib/irobotcreate2/basic_commands] Error 1`

`make[1]: [irobotcreate2ros/CMakeFiles/basic_commands.dir/all] Error 2`

`make[1]: Waiting for unfinished jobs....`

`CMakeFiles/irobotcreate2_lightweight.dir/src/irobotcreate2/OpenInterface.cpp.o: In function irobot::OpenInterface::getSensorPackets(int):`

`OpenInterface.cpp:(.text+0xf3c): undefined reference to serial::Serial::waitReadable()`

`CMakeFiles/irobotcreate2_lightweight.dir/src/irobotcreate2/OpenInterface.cpp.o: In function irobot::OpenInterface::streamSensorPackets():`

`OpenInterface.cpp:(.text+0x12a5): undefined reference to serial::Serial::waitReadable()`

`collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

`make[2]: [/home/myhome/Projects/ros/indigo/catkin_ws/devel/lib/irobotcreate2/irobotcreate2_lightweight] Error 1`

`make[1]: [irobotcreate2ros/CMakeFiles/irobotcreate2_lightweight.dir/all] Error 2`

`CMakeFiles/irobotcreate2.dir/src/irobotcreate2/OpenInterface.cpp.o: In function irobot::OpenInterface::getSensorPackets(int):`

`OpenInterface.cpp:(.text+0xf3c): undefined reference to serial::Serial::waitReadable()`

`CMakeFiles/irobotcreate2.dir/src/irobotcreate2/OpenInterface.cpp.o: In function irobot::OpenInterface::streamSensorPackets():`

`OpenInterface.cpp:(.text+0x12a5): undefined reference to serial::Serial::waitReadable()`

`collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

`make[2]: [/home/myhome/Projects/ros/indigo/catkin_ws/devel/lib/irobotcreate2/irobotcreate2] Error 1`

`make[1]: [irobotcreate2ros/CMakeFiles/irobotcreate2.dir/all] Error 2`

`make: [all] Error 2`

`Invoking "make" failed`

This makes me think that probably the compiler is not able to find the serial package. Now:

1. The problem with serial is only related to the `waitReadable()` function, as if I comment it from the code, the rest of serial references do not rise any compilation error, and the process ends without problem (I've the right configuration of CMake. I know also because I'm using the same CMakeFile I used on other machines, that is the one provided within the package).
2. I compiled this package (`irobotcreate2ros`) on other machines without problem, so maybe there's a wrong version of serial installed on my laptop. I went digging around on the internet, and I found that previous version of serial (http://rosindex.github.io/p/serial/), e.g. until v1.1.7, didn't have any `waitReadable()` method. I then checked which version was installed, and it says 1.2.1.
3. To be completely sure, I also went through the code of `serial.h` in `/opt/ros/indigo/include/serial/` to see if there was the `waitReadable()` method, and it's there (although there's just the function signature, of course).
4. Lastly, I thought it might depend on the `libserial` library, that I have installed (v0.6.0~rc1-0ubuntu4), but it doesn't seem to be related.

Now, I really don't know why the compiler is not able to solve that reference. I tried unistalling and reinstalling serial, but nothing changed. Any suggestion?

--- edit ---

The `CMakeLists.txt` file I'm using is exactly the same reported in this git repository https://github.com/MirkoFerrati/irobotcreate2ros/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229468/unable-to-compile-workspace-for-unsolved-reference-to-serial::serial::waitreadable/) by [McKracken82](https://answers.ros.org/users/26321/mckracken82/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2016-03-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-03-18**:
Would you edit your question adding the relevant parts of your `CMakeLists.txt`?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2016-03-18**:
I usually see this kind of problem when you have an older version of the library hanging around on your system somewhere but you've compiled your code against the newer headers. For example: https://github.com/wjwwood/serial/issues/126

**Comment by [McKracken82](https://answers.ros.org/users/26321/mckracken82/) on 2016-03-21**:
I've added the CMakeList file. William, I think that's the problem. I realized I've different version of libserial.so around the system, but I'm not getting where catkin is getting the serial package when compiling, nor the libserial.so to link with. I've moved them around, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the problem. There was a version of serial inside one of the package in my workspace (it's a shared workspace), so that the proper version of serial was overridden by this one. I created a new workspace, and the irobotcreate2ros package compiled perfectly.

---

Originally posted by [McKracken82](https://answers.ros.org/users/26321/mckracken82/) with karma: 73 on 2016-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0